# Data Parallelism in Ant Colony Optimization

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, ant, parallel-processing

I have been trying to understand how ACO optimization can be implemented with data parallelism. I have read some content after searching in Google. I only need the basic idea in simple way. Most of the papers are talking about everything else instead of the main thing in simple words.

What I understood so far is, we will make it work parallel by using multi-tasking(threading). But am not sure what each thread would do or how we could separate it into threads without causing trouble.

Does it means that we should create separate thread for each ants? But that would cause lots of threads to be created! So if there are 200 ants, then 200 threads?

Am still having confusion at this data parallelism topic in ACO. I would really love to hear in simple words on how we would implement it parallely.

Comment: Create the no of threads that your hardware handles (more if you have GPU) and distribute the number of ants among them and run in parallel.

Comment: Means each ant in each thread right?

Comment: No of ant/no of thread per thread and no of threads = no of processors*2 which you can get using programming. If GPU is present then you can schedule more thread into it.

Answer (score 0):

#### A few simple ideas to run ACO in parallel

Since you have already read up on ACO, here are a few simple ideas on ways to run ACO in parallel. Rather than getting caught up in multiple-threads and mutli-tasking, it might be helpful to think in terms of 'parallel compute resources' at your disposal.

ACO is one case of [Agent-Based Simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-based_model) (ABS), and ABS lends itself particularly well to parellization.

#### Simple Options

**Option 1**. Run a full version of ACO in each of the parallel resources.

Code your ACO algorithm, run it in parallel fashion. (Since there is a stochastic element to the algorithm, you can then look for the 'best' solution for your problem.)

**Option 2**. To explore effects of varying ACO parameters

Like any simulation approach, any ACO implementation has a large number of runtime parameters: Number of vertices, time to run, Number of ants, Pheromone evaporation rates, probability functions to choose path options and many more. When you mutliply these options, they add up to some large number of cases to be run. Divide up the work among your parallel compute resources.

The two options mentioned above are sometimes referred to as 'embarrassingly' parallel. Very easy to implement (think of it as a Design of Experiments) and you get back a whole matrix of results, and you can make conclusions by studying what effect the changes in the parameters had on the solution.

#### Option with solution sharing

**Option 3**: Master-Slave approach, with Partial Solution sharing

Going up one more level in complexity, we can use each node to contribute its 'knowledge/findings' to the overall problem solution. This is sometimes called a master-slave approach. The `master` is trying to solve the overall problem (Could be TSP, or some similar complex problem) and each 'slave' is solving some aspect of it, but with some fairly simple algorithm. The idea is that when *combined* they produce powerful results.

After a certain number of iterations, the solutions are passed back and forth, with 'bad' solutions thrown out. Some variant of the Map-Shuffle-Reduce paradigm would do that. The master evaluates the current best solution, and that is transferred back to each 'slave' node (Example: the latest overall pheromone levels are given to all the slave nodes). The next round of solving resumes.

Option 3 has tons of nuanced variations, and some people spend their entire lives improving various aspects of it.

Hope some of these ideas help.

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to read more to get some more ideas. I will get back to you after reading again. Thanks again for the detailed explanation.